# Is this plagiarizing of the Food Lion logo?

Tags: plagiarism

Do you think this is plagiarism and what could be done about it? The first one is the Food Lion Logo and the second one is the logo of a supermarket I went to.[image]

Comment: What is the name of the second supermarket?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should happen if a logo I made is similar to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92460/what-should-happen-if-a-logo-i-made-is-similar-to-another)

Answer (score 9):

Delhaize Group owns Food Lion, with corporate headquarters in Brussels Belgium. The red and black logo is typical of their European corporate and store identity. They own dozens of supermarket brands, several in the US. You've likely been to a Delhaize-owned market, and thus no plagiarism.

Please visit their website, or read a wikipedia entry here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhaize_Group

Also, I simply don't see any possibility that a food market would expose themselves with such blatant logo theft.

And by the way, I think it's good of you to be concerned and ready to act against IP fraud.